# Update EditText in Activity from Adapter

Tags: android

I feel like my mind has stopped working if I had to post a question about this but here it is. I have a simple Recyclerview Adapter `public class RecentEmojiAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter` with the following `OnCreateViewHolder` override

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
  {
   var listitem = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.item_emoji, parent, false);
   TextView E_IMAGE = listitem.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.emoji_image);
       EmojiViewHolder view = new EmojiViewHolder(listitem)
       {
          EImage = E_IMAGE                  
       };
   listitem.Click += (sender, e) => { OnClick(view.ECode); };            
   return view;
  }
```

And On click is the following

```
private void OnClick(string T)
   {
     try
       {
         Log.Info(TAG, T);                
       }
     catch(Exception X)
       {
         Log.Info(TAG, X.Message);
       }

   }
```

Works fine but I am just stuck on how do I access an `EditText` and update it using `EditText.Append(string)` - my `EditText` is in the Main Activity where RecyclerView is in a Fragment :)

Am I doing it all wrong:?

Comment: Your activity should implement a interface with certain method and pass it to the fragment and your fragment should implement a interface and pass it to the adapter.
when item of recyclerview clicked then you can call the method of interface implemented by fragment and the method of the fragment should call the interface method implemented in activity and you can get access to change text of edittext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you are passing a context on your adapter's constructor. You can use that and cast it as your activity. Then expose your EditText variable publicly on your MainActivity so the adapter can access it.

```
Context mContext;
List<DataModel> mData;

public YourAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> data){
    mContext = context;
    mData = data;
}
```

Then on your OnClick

```
MainActivity parentActivity = (MainActivity)mContext;
parentActivty.yourEditText.setText("Your text here")// Or do something about the edit text
```

Then on your MainActivity, declare the editText publicly

```
public EditText yourEditText;
```

Make sure that yourEditText is already instantiated via findViewById before accessing it.

I hope this helps. Cheers!